# FTX API in Google Apps Script not authenticating

Tags: cryptography

I've successfully connected to most other crypto exchanges but keep getting "success":false,"error":"Not logged in" when using FTX.

This is my code:

```
  var host = 'https://ftx.com/api';
  var endpoint ='/wallet/all_balances';
  var url = host + endpoint;

  var timestamp = ''+ new Date().getTime();
  var payload = timestamp + 'GET' + endpoint+'';

  var shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-256", "BYTES");
  shaObj.setHMACKey(secret, "BYTES");
  shaObj.update(payload);
  var signature = shaObj.getHMAC("HEX");

  var options = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      'FTX-KEY': key,
      'FTX-TS': timestamp,
      'FTX-SIGN': signature
      },
    muteHTTPExceptions: 'true'
  }

  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var data   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

```
var host = 'https://ftx.com';
var endpoint ='/api/wallet/all_balances';
```